# How to share List in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, list, silverlight-4.0

In the Silverlight application I have 2 Functions
1st one:

```
private void LoadData()
        {
            ServiceReference2.Service1Client webService = new ServiceReference2.Service1Client();
            webService.GetContentCompleted += new EventHandler<ServiceReference2.GetContentCompletedEventArgs>(webService_GetContentCompleted);
            webService.GetContentAsync();

        }
```

2nd one:

```
private void webService_GetContentCompleted(object sender, ServiceReference2.GetContentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            IEnumerable<ServiceReference2.MediaContent> list = e.Result as IEnumerable<ServiceReference2.MediaContent>;
            dataGrid1.ItemsSource = list;
        }
```

How can I get `list` from other functons in my project?

Comment: I don't really understand your question.  What do you mean by "How can I get list from other functons in my project?"  Do you want to populate your grid ItemsSource from something other than the web service or do you want to call the GetContentAsync web service from other locations in your Silverlight project?

Comment: If I create 3rd function how it would look like? How private void 3rd_Func (?????){ something = list;  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
    private void LoadData()
    {
        ServiceReference2.Service1Client webService = new ServiceReference2.Service1Client();
        webService.GetContentCompleted += new EventHandler<ServiceReference2.GetContentCompletedEventArgs>(webService_GetContentCompleted);
        webService.GetContentAsync();
    }

    private void webService_GetContentCompleted(object sender, ServiceReference2.GetContentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        IEnumerable<ServiceReference2.MediaContent> list = e.Result as IEnumerable<ServiceReference2.MediaContent>;
        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = list;

        ThirdMethod(list);
    }

    private void ThirdMethod(IEnumerable<ServiceReference2.MediaContent> list)
    {
        something = list;
    }
```